# sshpass throwing an error when I use it with filebot script

Tags: 18.04, server, scripts

I am trying to run this `filebot.sh`

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USERNAME@192.168.1.52 filebot -script fn:amc --output "/mnt/local/disk.slab/medialibrary" --action move -non-strict "/mnt/local/disk.slab/downloads/usenet/other" --log-file amc.log --def excludeList="/mnt/local/disk.slab/downloads/amc.txt" discord=https://discord.com/api/webhooks/ABS/HYUNDAI-SUZUKI clean=y movieFormat="/mnt/local/disk.slab/medialibrary/movies/{ny.colon(' - ')}/{folder.name}"
```

But getting this error `sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected "("` and if I remove this `(' - ')` everything works fine. Thank you so much

Comment: @bac0n I tried like that but not working :(

Comment: Hooray @bac0n it worked I forgot to put `" "` :) thank you so much for quick help. You are a star

Comment: Sorry guys I thought it worked but actually its not. I have this `"/mnt/local/disk.slab/medialibrary/movies/{ny.colon\(' - '\)}/{folder.name}"` and I am getting this error `ScriptException: SyntaxError: Missing ')'`

Comment: `{ny.colon\\\(' - '\\\)}` this one gives me this error `bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('` and this one `{ny.colon'( - )'}` gives me `ScriptException: SyntaxError: Missing ')'`

Comment: I got this error now `ScriptException: SyntaxError: Unexpected input: '\'; Expecting <EOF>`

Comment: last attempt ..... ok `... USERNAME@192.168.1.52 'filebot -script fn:amc --output ... movieFormat="/mnt/.../{ny.colon('\'' - '\'')}/{folder.name}"'` ... you enclose the hole line from filebot to the end

Comment: Awe thank you so much for quick and workable responses. `FileBot: Done ヾ(＠⌒ー⌒＠)ノ` Last one worked :) You are amazing. Thanks. Its my first post here. Do I need to do anything to close this and question? Thanks and have a great weekend

Comment: I'll clean out all my comments and just leave that last one.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help again and I have learn a new thing from you. Thanks